# Continuity; simple proof by definition.

Tags: calculus

I've got some working below that needs verification.

I'm worried about how I can include something that says "Because our domain is $\Bbb R/\{0\}$, we can write this..." because clearly it is needed otherwise I'd be able to proof $f(x) = 1/x$ is continuous using this proove over all $\Bbb R$.

I've written my proof so far for convenience of copy and paste for the person answering this.

Proof;
recall the definition; we say that $f: I \Rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous at $a \in I \subseteq \Bbb R$ if; $$\lim_{x\to a} = f(a)$$

For this to be true we need to show; $$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in I$$ such that $$ 0 < |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$

Work backwards to find appropriate $\delta$ for the real proof:
$|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon \implies |1/x - 1/a| < \epsilon$ $\implies -\epsilon < 1/x - 1/a < \epsilon$ $\implies |x-a|<1/\epsilon = \delta $

Now for the formal proof;

Given some $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta$ = $1/\epsilon$

$0<|x-a| < \delta \implies -\delta < x - a < \delta \implies -1/\delta < 1/x - 1/a < 1/\delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$

So my question really is; how do I use this to include this works **only** because $I = \Bbb R/ \{0\}$

Comment: The right-hand side of $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}{f(x)}=f(a)$ simply is not defined. Thus, there's no value to which it can converge.

You can forcefully assign a value at $x=0$ (say, $f(0)=0$), but the function will still be discontinuous because the left and right limit do not agree.

Comment: $f(a) = 1/a$ **is precisely** the definition of $f(a)$ with respect to this proof and $f(x)$ as shown, so $f(a)$ is defined. I don't know where you're coming from?

Comment: Perhaps I missed out something…but in your work backwards, how does $-\epsilon < 1/x - 1/a < \epsilon $ implies the next step? I have same doubt with the second step to third step in your formal proof.

Comment: Using the definition of modulus, that is $|x|<y \implies -y<x<y$ (the opposite way is true also), I did skip a few fundamental steps because I got sick of writing in MathJax. But it is provable; take inverse of everything, put back in modulus form via definition and voila.

Comment: I meant that it wasn't defined at $x=0$. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Indeed, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1x = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac 1x = - \infty$ so $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1x$ does not exist. This follows $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

You need to prove $\lim_{x \to a} \frac 1x= \frac 1a$ for all $a \in \mathbf{R}\setminus \{0 \}$. For more general:

> Let $f,g$ be functions defined on interval $D$ that contains $a$. Suppose $f,g$ have limit $L,G$ at $x=a$, respectively and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) \ne 0$. Then
>   $$\lim_{x \to a} \left( \frac fg \right) (x)= \frac{ \lim_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}g(x)}.$$

You can see [here](https://combigeomery.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/learning-calculus-ii-limits-laws-of-functions-and-related-theorems/) for the proof, look for Theorem 13.

Comment: So my proof given to show that $1/x$ is continuous over $\Bbb R /\{0\}$ actually is perfectly valid?

Comment: I afraid not...allow me some time to generate my version of proof.

Comment: @FloSuess I doubt that. You need to check the step $-\delta < x - a < \delta \implies -1/\delta < 1/x - 1/a < 1/\delta$.

Comment: Mhmm, @ToanQuangPham would it be something about how x and a could be 0? Would you just add some assumption, like, because $ x \in \Bbb R/\{0\} \implies a \in \Bbb R/\{0\}$ I'd need an explanation because this doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @FloSuess The limit $\lim_{x \to a} 1/x=1/a$ for $a \ne 0$. That's what you need to show. Don't write $x \in \mathbf{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}  \implies a \in \mathbf{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. i.e. When you write the proof, consider two cases $a \ne 0$ and $a=0$, prove that $\lim_{x \to a} 1/x=1/a$ for $a \ne 0$, $\lim_{x \to a} 1/x$ does not exist for $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I just prove $1/x$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$. Perhaps you shall generalize my proof on $I$.

Pick any $a > 0$. Pick any $\epsilon > 0$. Take $\delta = \min\{a/2, \epsilon a^2/2\}$. Here the $\delta$ must depends on $a$. Otherwise, $1/x$ would be uniformly continuous on $(0,+\infty)$!

Pick any $x \in (0,+\infty)$. If $|x - a|< \delta$, then $x > a/2$ and then $xa > a^2/2$. $1/(xa) < 1/(a^2/2)$.

$$\implies \bigg|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a} \bigg| =  \bigg|\frac{a - x}{xa} \bigg| < \frac{\epsilon a^2/2}{a^2/2} =\epsilon  $$

---

P.S. A function being uniformly continuous on $I$ means that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall a, x \in I$, $|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$. Such $\delta$ is independent on choice of $a$. For example, for the silly function $x \mapsto x$, you can always take $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: Mhmm so together with showing continuity on $(0,-\infty)$ will provide the full proof. I see. But, how does $|x-a| < \delta \implies x > a/2$??

Comment: $|x - a |< \delta \leq a/2 \implies x \in (a - a/2, a+a/2)$.